# PHP Button to carry out query and refresh page

Tags: php, html

I have two buttons on my page (yes and no).
I have a function on another page 'choice.php' that updates a database based on this decision. This function takes 'yes' or 'no' as inputs. Therefore I would like each button to run the choice.php page, with 'yes' or 'no' depending on button pressed, and then refresh the current page. Currently I have tried (for 'yes'):

```
echo "<form></br>";
echo "<input type='button' value = 'yes' Method ='POST' ACTION = 'choice.php'>";
echo "</form>";
```

But I am unsure where to go from here. The choice.php page has:

```
function choice('yes'/'no');
```

Comment: Move the `action` and `method` attributes to your `<form>` tag. Then give your `<input>` a `name` attribute then access the value using `$_POST['inputnamehere']`

Comment: Read from the `superglobal` array `$_POST` which holds all POST data in a associative array where the name property of the post is the key and the actual data is the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params should be comma separated, but you don't really need params when taking from superglobal array. However, you only need to call the function if `'yes'` for example:

```
<form action="choice.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="choice" value="yes" />
<input type="submit" name="choice" value="no" /> <!-- You'd better use radio buttons -->
</form>

<?php    
function choice() {
    if ($db->query("UPDATE ..... ;")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if (isset($_POST['choice']) && $_POST['choice'] == 'yes') {
    choice();
}
else {
    echo 'no';
}
?>
```

---

Ofcourse you can have multiple if's, but I don't think it will help you enough:

```
if (isset($_POST['choice']) && $_POST['choice'] == 'yes') {
     //something;
}
elseif (isset($_POST['choice']) && $_POST['choice'] == 'no') {
     //something else;
}
elseif (isset($_POST['choice']) && $_POST['choice'] == 'maybe') {
     //something else;
}
```

If you want the function to update db with the value from the user, you could use something like this:

```
function choice() {
    $choices = array('yes', 'no', 'maybe', 'dunno'); //predefined choices
    if (in_array($_POST['choice'], $choices)) { //checks if the user input is one of the predefined choices (yes, no, maybe or dunno)
        if($db->query("UPDATE table1 SET userchoice = '{$_POST['choice']}' WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}';")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


if (isset($_POST['choice'])) choice(); //so here you don't need (not necessary, but you can) to check if the value is the one you want. If it's set, you call choice(), then the function checks if it's in the array of predefined choices, so if it is - it will update, if it's not it will return false
```

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one parameter? I am trying to associate the choice with the current user so ideally I would like to pass the 'choice.php' page with both the choice (yes/no) and also the User ID

Comment: you can use `elseif` statement. But what you really want to do? Do update the table with what the user has chosen? Let me try to edit the answer

Comment: @user1045280 I have edited the answer, not sure if it is what you really want, so if there are any questions, ask :) I made a simple function which checks if the posted value is either `yes`, `no`, `maybe` or `dunno` and updates the database with this value. If it's not it returns false. Afterwards if someone makes a post request the function is called

Comment: So the section (db->query update). I have the second page 'choices.php' that does a bit of fiddling and then updates the database. Is it possible for the button to run that pages (choices.php) and then reload the original page (with the yes/no buttons?)

Comment: It's possible either by `header()` or ajax

Comment: How do I get header() to activate with a button click?

Comment: You cannot without submitting. You can have submit which goes to choice.php, if everything is OK, it activates header() to redirect back. That was the idea?

Comment: Ok, so I added `header(Location: buttons.php)` but it doesnt redirect?

Comment: No output should be shown, also exit() or die() after header(). And "Location: buttons.php" should be quoted

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `header` on your `choice.php` after your database operations finishes.

`header('Location: *where your form page is*');`

Another way is to do an ajax post using javascript

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have something like this:

```
<form method='POST' action='choice.php'>
<tr>
 <td><input type="submit" name="answer" value="yes"></td>
 <td><input type="submit" name="answer" value="no"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

and in the `PHP` file you can use the `POST` method to check for the answer, whether it was `yes` or `no`

```
if($_POST['answer'] == 'yes') {
 //do something
}
if($_POST['answer'] == 'no') {
 //do something else
}
```